# List of available “application/…” media types

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type

Anyone know the list of available `application/…` media types? It is because my website will be having different types of downable documents such as *doc*, *docx*, *txt*, *pdf* etc.

I need to know the available `application/…` for the HTTP header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a list of MIME types:

http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear to me what you're asking for, but the official list of application MIME subtypes can be found [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/).

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not sure about the media type, you can always use `application/octet-stream`.